# deadlock errors when doing benchmark test on mysql

Tags: mysql

I wonder why so many deadlock error appear when I do benchmarksql test on mysql.

The error appears when the parameter `terminals` is greater than 32.

Detailed error report

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:123)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:634)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:414)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1113)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1381)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at jTPCCTData.executeNewOrder(jTPCCTData.java:417)
    at jTPCCTData.execute(jTPCCTData.java:95)
    at jTPCCTerminal.executeTransactions(jTPCCTerminal.java:277)
    at jTPCCTerminal.run(jTPCCTerminal.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The information of the machine is attached, I disabled smt.

[image: Information of the machine]

Comment: Please dont oist text information as images. It would also help to know what query trips it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` after the deadlock.